# "Если бы ..., то (без второго бы)" - корректно ли?

Tags: сослагательное-наклонение

Встретилось такое предложение на очень серьезном уровне

> В случае, если бы они были принуждены предоставить льготы, то эти
> льготы аннулируются данным договором.

Корректно ли оно? Может правильнее писать

> В случае, если они были принуждены предоставить льготы, то эти
> льготы аннулируются данным договором.

Comment: Я с вами согласен

Comment: Это версальский договор между странами. http://militera.org/books/pdf/docs/sb_versal.pdf статья 293